# Identify entities of same type in YAML (structure vs content)

Tags: yaml

I have a collection of entities that I need to express in YAML. Each entity has an identifier that is unique. I see two different ways to handle this.

### Alternative 1

```
entities:
    - entity1:
          data: 123
    - entity2:
          data: 567
```

### Alternative 2

```
entity:
    - id: entity1
      data: 123
    - id: entity2
      data: 567
```

Alternative one looks somewhat clearer but mixes structure and content in a way that I'm not completely comfortable with.<sup>1</sup>

What's the best practice? I've looked in the YAML specification (ver 1.2) but didn't find anything of relevance. Ex 2.4 and 2.6 could actually indicate that both would be ok.

<sub>1. I've worked with XML in the past, so alternative 2 is much more familiar.</sub>

Comment: Its seems as you are going to import/export some database data, then yaml is not the right  choice for such a task. Yaml is designed for human being  for storing some configuration data mostly limited in adequate way to be readable and editable. And how to store such a data, is up to you.  I do no think there is something as "best pratice".

Comment: I intend to use this for configuration. "Entity" is just a generalisation, the actual file will of course contain something more specific. A list of inputs and outputs in the code I'm currently working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML doesn't dictate a „best practice“. A simple argument for the second alternative is that the ID is part of the data object, so if in your code you ever want to get the ID from a reference to the data, this is what you want to use. However, that argument is flawed: The config structure does not need to match the internal data structure as you can simply transform it after loading.

Therefore, the only thing that matters is what is better for the author who writes this YAML. And I'd say, neither of those alternatives are ideal, since this one is simpler:

```yaml
entities:
    entity1:
        data: 123
    entity2:
        data: 567
```

If the names are unique, the only reason you'd want to have the key-value pairs in separate sequence items is if their order is of significance, as the YAML spec says that order of mapping pairs must not convey content information.

My experience on YAML problems here on SO is also that the more indentation levels you introduce, the easier people are confused. The line `- entity1:` introduces *two* indentation levels – one for the sequence item indicator `-` and one for the mapping containing the key `entity1`. This should not be done unless necessary.

YAML models structured data, so the structure is part of the content and I don't really see how you can *not* mix structure with content. Mind that mapping keys in YAML do not explicitly carry type information like elements in XML do. In fact, the type of some subtree may be defined by its content (which is the reason `true` is usually read as a boolean, but `123` at the same place is read as an integer). Therefore, I don't think it's wise to apply XML thinking to YAML.

Also, think about whether you need the root mapping with the key `entities`. This can be dropped if the file contains nothing else. If, however, other sets of items follow, it is justified. However, if those other sets of items share the uniqueness of their IDs with the entities, you may be better off doing

```yaml
entity1: !entity
  data: 123
entity2: !entity
  data: 567
blob1: !blob
  blobbiness: 1
```

This shows how you can have items with different structure and semantics on the same level by using *tags* (`!entity` / `!blob`). The downside is that tags are not widely employed and could be an exotic feature your users are unfamiliar with.

Comment: Yes, I did mess up alternative 1, it should be the way you suggest. Thank for an extensive and well reasoned answer.